# React native - how to trigger screen render on navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

i'm making an app, and i have a screen that lists profiles, and when i touch a profile name, it navigates to another screen for editing, and on that screen i have a button for update the user profile and navigating to the list profile screen, but when i do that, the list screen doesn't update so the profile information doesn't change, in order for it to update i have to open the app again.
how can i make it so when i edit the profile on the edit screen and navigate back, the list screen re renders and shows the new information of the profile
pd: i'm using class components and navigation V6

Comment: If you are using redux then you can achieve screen update via ```connect``` or ```useSelector``` [hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

You may also use react-navigation [events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect) to fetch updated profile data when your profile list screen is focused.

Answer (score 2):

To rerender your data when the profile list screen is focused, you can use the useFocusEffect hook. This hook will run every time the screen is focused. You can place a function in the hook to retrieve the updated profile data.

More can be found in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/).